# Getting the "src" property of image elements

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I'm building a product display component where the selected image is displayed as the main one. How do I get the source of each image in the useState? Should I pass it as a parameter to the function? I'm new to React so help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [insertImage, setInsertImage] = useState("/images/camaro.jpg");

  function setImage() {
    setInsertImage("SRC REQUIRED HERE");
  }
  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col gap-3 max-w-3xl m-auto">
      <div className="w-full">
        <img src={insertImage} className="h-full w-full"></img>
      </div>
      <div className="flex gap-2">
        <div className="w-96" onClick={setImage}>
          <img
            src="/images/camaro.jpg"
            className="transition-opacity delay-75 hover:opacity-70 cursor-pointer active:scale-95"
          ></img>
        </div>
        <div className="w-96" onClick={setImage}>
          <img
            src="/images/mclaren.jpg"
            className="transition-opacity delay-75 hover:opacity-70 cursor-pointer active:scale-95"
          ></img>
        </div>
        <div className="w-96" onClick={setImage}>
          <img
            src="/images/gtr.jpg"
            className="transition-opacity delay-75 hover:opacity-70 cursor-pointer active:scale-95"
          ></img>
        </div>
        <div className="w-96" onClick={setImage}>
          <img
            src="/images/mclaren.jpg"
            className="transition-opacity delay-75 hover:opacity-70 cursor-pointer active:scale-95"
          ></img>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access the wrapper element via the click event using `currentTarget` ([MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget)). From there, you can search for the contained image using a query selector ([MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)), and then read the `src` property:

Updated `setImage()`:

```
function setImage(e) {
  const src = e.currentTarget.querySelector('img').src
  setInsertImage(src)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To do this, you can change `setImage()` to have a parameter accepting the source, so that you can have the selected image show up:

```js
function App() {
  const [insertImage, setInsertImage] = useState("/images/camaro.jpg");

  function setImage(src) {
    setInsertImage(src);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div className="w-full">
        <img src={insertImage} className="h-full w-full"></img>
      </div>
      <div className="w-96" onClick={() => setImage("/images/mclaren.jpg")}>
        <img
          src="/images/mclaren.jpg"
          className="transition-opacity delay-75 hover:opacity-70 cursor-pointer active:scale-95"
        ></img>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```